# How to integrate counting frequency of characters in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some simple HTML code

```
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type text...."></textarea>
<a id="button" class="button"></a>
<textarea id="result" disabled></textarea>
```

and I have a javascript code

```
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};
```

I just want to integrate js with HTML to count each character frequency inside of textarea with id="text" and show result inside of textarea with id="result". I have tried to use

```
document.getElementById("text").value;
```

but something goes wrong and still not working. There is any way to do this in easy way?

Comment: `getFrequency(document.getElementById("text").value)` should indeed give you the result you want - but when are you calling this? If you just call it on page load, it will just count the frequencies in "Type text....". Presumably you want to call this when the button is clicked, and use the resulting object to populate some other HTML element? But you don't show what you have tried, or what your intended result is.

Comment: Please specify what is going wrong, something is simply to unspecific :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById("text");
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const value = textArea.value.trim();
  const res = getFrequency(value);
  console.log(JSON.stringify([...res]));
  result.innerText = `(${[...res].join("), (")})`;
})

function getFrequency(str){
  return str.split("").reduce((a,c)=>a.set(c, (a.get(c) || 0) + 1), new Map());
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div > div {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <textarea id="text" placeholder="Type text....">
      Some text to check the count of characters
  </textarea>
  <div>
  <button id="button" class="button">Click me</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `a.set(c, (a.get(c) || 0) + 1)` do, if you anyhow refactored the base code? :)

Comment: @Icepickle nice catch thanks. I just checked documentation and realized a.set actually returns the map object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it while typing you can use the `keyup` event on the textarea, in the following way

```js
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const textbox = document.getElementById('text');
  const result = document.getElementById('result');
  
  textbox.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    const frequency = getFrequency( textbox.value );
    result.value = Object.keys( frequency ).map( key => `${key}: ${frequency[key]}` ).join('\n');
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type text...."></textarea>
<a id="button" class="button"></a>
<textarea id="result" disabled></textarea>
```

if you want to do it upon button click, you could change the previous code like so:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',  function() {
  const frequency = getFrequency( textbox.value );
  result.value = Object.keys( frequency ).map( key => `${key}: ${frequency[key]}` ).join('\n');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```js
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};

document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function(){
  var str = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var result = getFrequency(str);
  document.getElementById('result').value = JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type text...." ></textarea>
<button id="myButton" class="button">Count</button>
<textarea id="result" disabled></textarea>
```